# How remove a specific css class's without disturbing exsisting specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting dynamic class in my list code, so i am not ware what will be the class name but due to my code the specific class is removed for eg. regularaccount, sampleaccount1, saveaccount2

I want my existing specific class which is dynamic i can't guess what it will be should be removed

only these to class need to be removed

**here is js**

```
$('#acntLst li').each(function(){
    var mc = new Hammer(this);
    var currentEle = $(this);
     mc.on("swipeleft swiperight", function(ev) {


     if(ev.type == 'swipeleft') {
             console.log(ev.type);
          currentEle.siblings().removeClass('marl-300').removeClass('marr-300');
          currentEle.addClass('marl-300');

       } else if(ev.type == 'swiperight') {
               console.log(ev.type);
               currentEle.siblings().removeClass('marl-300').removeClass('marr-300');
        currentEle.addClass('marr-300');

       } /*else if(ev.type == 'press') {
        currentEle.siblings().removeClass();
        currentEle.removeClass();
              alert('touch key pressed');
       }*/

    });
 });
```

**and html code**

```
<ul  id="acntLst">

<li class="regularaccount"></li>
<li class="sampleaccount1"></li>
<li class="saveaccount2"></li>
</ul>
```

for swiper i am using hammer code its working fine

Comment: Please describe more clearly what it is that you want to achieve. It's difficult to help if people don't know what you need help with.

Comment: i want to keep my dynamic class .. but i am sure which i have to delete is marl-300 and marr-300.. in my siblings elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED:

Use each loop for siblings because there is more than one sibling:

```
$('#acntLst li').each(function(){
    var mc = new Hammer(this);
    var currentEle = $(this);
     mc.on("swipeleft swiperight", function(ev) {


     if(ev.type == 'swipeleft') {
             console.log(ev.type);
              currentEle.siblings().each(function(){
                  $(this).removeClass('marl-300').removeClass('marr-300');
               });
          currentEle.addClass('marl-300');

       } else if(ev.type == 'swiperight') {
               console.log(ev.type);
               currentEle.siblings().each(function(){
                  $(this).removeClass('marl-300').removeClass('marr-300');
               });
        currentEle.addClass('marr-300');

       } /*else if(ev.type == 'press') {
        currentEle.siblings().removeClass();
        currentEle.removeClass();
              alert('touch key pressed');
       }*/

    });
```

});

Comment: i want keep a my dynamic class .. but i am sure which i have to delete is marl-300 and marr-300.. but your code will remove all my class current element

Comment: so do you want to delete marl-300 and marr-300 for all siblings?

Comment: yes i want remove marl-300 and marr-300, with effecting the other class

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list